# How can i sum dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My code is below

```
<?php                       
foreach($query2->result() as $row2)
{                           
    $sub_head_id = $row2->sub_head_id;
?>                          
      <tr>
<?php 
      $query3 = $this->db->select('farm_id')->get('spf_farm_info');                              $she_am_total = 0;
      foreach($query3->result() as $row3)
      {
          $farm_id_inner = $row3->farm_id;
?>
      <td>
<?php 
          $s_h_e_amount = $this->report_model->get_amount($farm_id_inner,$head_id,$sub_head_id);
?>
    </td>
<?php
      }
?>
    <td>
<?php
    $total += $s_h_e_amount;
?>
     </td>
     </tr>
<?php
        }
        }
?>
```

Basically i want to know how can i solve it,

```
<tr>
<?php 
      $query3 = $this->db->select('farm_id')->get('spf_farm_info');                              $she_am_total = 0;
      foreach($query3->result() as $row3)
      {

?>
      <td>
<?php 
          echo "Total :";
          echo $total;
?>
    </td>
<?php
      }
?>
<td>
    Grand Total:
</td>
</tr>
```

Here, Table column will increase dynamically, and will get different value every td(may be 2/3/4/..) from get_amount function.

Now i want to sum every tr's value according to column.
here it will be sum dynamically which will be show.

[image]

Please help me how can i solve properly

Comment: don't know code igniter, but I'd use SUM in mysql-query.

Comment: Thanks a lot michi. Sometimes forget so easy thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here , since using Codeigniter, it will be used that select_sum(). then will get proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Simple SOlution is Take Four Variables

```
$Cola_total=0;
$Colb_total=0;
$Colc_total=0;
$Cold_total=0;
```

in your loop sum these Columns

foreach($array as $val){

```
echo "<tr><td>$val[0]</td> <td>$val[1]</td> <td>$val[2]</td><td>$val[3]</td></tr>";

$Cola_total=+$val[0];
$Colb_total=+$val[1];
$Colc_total=+$val[2];
$Cold_total=+$val[3];
```

}

and after the loop put the sum in last row

```
echo "<tr><td>$Cola_total</td> <td>$Colb_total</td> <td>$Colc_total</td><td>$Cold_total</td></tr>";
```

it may give you some idea